# Using comparison operator on custom objects

Tags: python, class

I have the following code:

```
from typing import Optional

class Tree:
    class Tree:

def __init__(self):
    self.root: Optional[Node] = None

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.root.data}"



class Node:

def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
```

I have this class. I am trying to find maximum data element in my tree. The algorithm I created keeps a temporary element and updates the temporary element if it finds a value greater than this element. At first, I make my temporary element value 0 and then do the following:

```
if tree.data > temp:
    temp = tree.data
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'
```

How can I use the ">" operator in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like `'int' and 'Node'`? I would think `tree.data` is not a `Node`, but some other type. The code you want is  probably `if tree.data > temp.data: temp = tree`.

Comment: temp is a int value.

Comment: Then `tree.data` seems to be incorrectly getting defined as a `Node`, rather than the intended `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Give an implementation of the `__gt__` dunder method for the `Node` object. This tells Python what basis to compare `Node` objects on:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.data > other.data
```

Comment: Is there a resource you can recommend me to learn dunder methods?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__